# %matplotlib notebook magic command in jupyter works only intermittently

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I really like the `%matplotlib notebook` magic command for making plots interactive (zoomable) in Jupyter notebooks. But I've found that command often (maybe always?) fails to work if it's called within the same cell as import commands. For example, here's a screenshot of a Jupyter Notebook showing a plot that is not interactive, despite having called `%matplotlib notebook` in the first cell:

[image]

But if I split that first cell such that the magic command is in its own cell, I get an interactive plot as desired. Screenshot below (note that interactive buttons surrounding the plot in this image):

[image]

I've just been trying to train myself put the `%matplotlib notebook` call in its own cell, as shown in the second example, but I'm curious if there's some known underlying reason why this is occuring?

Comment: I couldn't recreate this issue but I'll note that what seems to be happening is that something seems to be stopping your Fig 1.

Comment: I did some more testing and realized that it appears to be Python version dependent. I made three fresh environments, one each for Python 3.6.13, 3.7.10, and 3.8.8. I did a pip install numpy and pip install matplotlib in each. I got the above behavior (non interactive plot) only in the Python 3.7 environment. Python 3.6 and 3.8 both gave interactive plots, even with the magic command in the top cell with the imports. That still doesn't explain why it's happening, however.